# SQL SELECT DISTINCT columns then add another column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following query to get DISTINCT records I'm interested in.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
USERID, Policy_Name, Account_Type, WEEKNUM, EMPLOYEETYPE, MANAGERID
FROM table1
```

In table 1 there is also a column called Acc-Check.

I want to add Acc-Check to the results of the above query during or afterward without affecting the 'DISTINCT' number of results i.e. the output will then be:

```
USERID, Policy_Name, Account_Type, WEEKNUM, EMPLOYEETYPE, MANAGERID, Acc-Check
```

None of the columns are PK. Open to any suggestions and can edit the table as necessary.

```
USERID             nvarchar(MAX)
Policy_Name        nvarchar(MAX)
Account_Type       nvarchar(MAX)
WEEKNUM            nvarchar(MAX)
EMPLOYEETYPE       nvarchar(MAX)
MANAGERID          nvarchar(MAX)
Acc_Check          nvarchar(MAX)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY` to get same result as before, add max("Acc-Check") to get one acc-check value.

```
SELECT 
USERID, Policy_Name, Account_Type, WEEKNUM, EMPLOYEETYPE, MANAGERID, max("Acc-Check")
FROM table1
group by USERID, Policy_Name, Account_Type, WEEKNUM, EMPLOYEETYPE, MANAGERID
```

Comment: This is the answer for what I asked but doesn't actually solve my problem in a bigger context but that's my fault because I wasn't specific enough. Thanks!!